# iOSで、画像を表示するライブラリを探しています。

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c

Twitter公式クライアントやLINEのアプリで採用されている画像表示のためのライブラリを探しています。
添付画像のように、背景は黒、真ん中に画像があり、右上にバツボタンがあります。
大切なのは、画像を指で上にドラッグするとそれに従って画像も上に移動します。
また、画面外に画像を移動させると、自動的に元の画面を開きます。
このようなライブラリは存在するのでしょうか？

[image: Twitter公式クライアントによる画像表示]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

僕の知る限りでは全く同じものは存在しませんが、非常によく似たものとしてIDMPhotoBrowserやJTSImageViewControllerといったものがあります。

オススメはJTSの方です
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/jtsimageviewcontroller/